# What is the rationale behind open sourcing teaching material to help improve education?

Tags: educational-resources

Teaching materials like textbooks or work sheets can be opened up to free redistribution and the option to change it for everyone. What are the arguments for doing this, with respect to how it can benefit the quality of education? Are there examples or is there evidence of it having the effect?

Comment: @CloseVoters Please tell us you're reasoning for close votes.

Comment: Agreed with @Zizouz212 - while it's not mandatory, reasoning your close votes in comments does help us scope the site out, so is very useful in private beta.

Comment: Right, I voted to close because I think answers to this question would be based entirely on opinions or anecdotes (beyond the generality that allowing people to modify stuff is better...).

Comment: This question might be more likely to be reopened if edited to specifically ask for evidence, rather than opinions. Although it would be much the same question, it would attract more definitive answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Sure it can but...**

It would not necessarily be better than regular materials. School boards often spend money getting customized programs / information. This may not always happen if all the information is open sourced.

Some examples of this:

The catholic school board in Toronto has used companies to get custom software for its students:

http://www.konverge.com/Custom-Software-Design-Clients/

Comment: It would not necessarily be better, [but certainly cheaper when no customization is necessary](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/427/what-risks-are-involved-for-a-publisher-if-he-decides-to-release-teaching-mater/433#433).